# how to remove trailing spaces from the bracket which is a substring of another string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-cleaning

I'm using SQL and some of column values are represented as `{3P Test   } * 1 + 0.45%`.

Here I have trailing spaces after **Test** and I want to update that to `{3P Test} * 1 + 0.45%`. How can I update that column so that trailing spaces in brackets are removed?

Comment: MY column value is {3P Test spaces spaces  } * 1 + 0.45%..In description spaces after Test are trimmed by stackOveflow.

Comment: Does this work ? REPLACE(columnName,' }' ,'}')

Comment: @KiranHegde : do u mean something like SELECT REPLACE('columnName',' }','}'); ??

Comment: Yeah, but iteratively, because we can have more than one space before }

Comment: I updated the question to put the string as inline code so as to not remove the trailing spaces.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it is Oracle oriented.

Comment: I'm very new to database and sql server..can anyone give me syntax for sql server?

Comment: `UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = NastyStringManipulation([Column]);`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys..I used following query and it worked                                           UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_COLUMN = REPLACE (MY_COLUMN, ' }', '}') WHERE   MY_COLUMN LIKE '% }%';

Comment: If you answer your own question with a comment and stop reading the answers you are making a mess of the site and wasting the time and effort of everybody who responded to your question.

Comment: Answer was given by @ultraCommit and then he deleted his answer because he thought his ans was oracle oriented. I took his answer and tried to convert it into sql format and luckily it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one-time update, or if there aren't that many rows, then an iterative approach (as has been suggested in comments on the question) can work, but this is *not* something you want to do if there is a lot of data as each iteration of `UPDATE` is a transaction (unless you explicitly execute `BEGIN TRANSACTION` prior to the `WHILE` loop, but then if that operation takes a while it will block the table from other operations).

For example:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (String NVARCHAR(4000));
INSERT INTO @TestTable (String) VALUES (N'{3P Test   } * 1 + 0.45%');

SELECT * FROM @TestTable;

WHILE (EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM @TestTable tmp
          WHERE tmp.String LIKE N'% }%'
          )
      )
BEGIN
   UPDATE TOP (100) tmp -- do this in batches to reduce transaction size
   SET tmp.String = REPLACE(tmp.String, N' }', N'}')
   FROM @TestTable tmp
   WHERE tmp.String LIKE N'% }%';
END;

SELECT * FROM @TestTable;
```

**OR**, here is a simplified version of the `CHARINDEX` idea proposed by @Jodrell that uses a CTE rather than multiple subqueries (does not need to `JOIN` to the base table) and breaks the string into just 2 instead of 3 pieces:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (String NVARCHAR(4000));
INSERT INTO @TestTable (String) VALUES (N'{3P Test               } * 1 + 0.45%');
INSERT INTO @TestTable (String) VALUES (N'{3P Test     4       } * 1 + 0.45%');

SELECT * FROM @TestTable;

WHILE (EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM @TestTable tmp
          WHERE tmp.String LIKE N'% }%'
          )
      )
BEGIN

   ;WITH cte AS
   (
      SELECT TOP (100)
             tmp.String,
             CHARINDEX(N'}', tmp.String) AS [RightBracketLocation]
      FROM @TestTable tmp
      WHERE tmp.String LIKE N'% }%'
   )
   UPDATE cte
   SET cte.String =
             RTRIM(SUBSTRING(cte.String, 1, (cte.[RightBracketLocation] - 1)))
             + SUBSTRING(cte.String, [RightBracketLocation], 4000)
   FROM cte;

END;

SELECT * FROM @TestTable;
```

But, if this is to be a common operation, then something more straight forward and direct is better, such as Regular Expressions. There are no built-in Regular Expression functions so you need to use SQLCLR to get that functionality. For example:

```
DECLARE @Test NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @Test = N'{3P Test   } * 1 + 0.45%';

SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace(@Test, N'\s+}', N'}', -1, 1, N'IgnoreCase');
```

In the example I am using the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_24785505) library (which I am the author of, but the Regular Expression functions are available in the Free version).

Comment: thanks a lot for quick response..I used                                        UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_COLUMN = REPLACE (MY_COLUMN, ' }', '}') WHERE   MY_COLUMN LIKE '% }%'; and it worked perfectly

Comment: @sach: you are welcome. You should probably up-vote the answers from myself and AHiggens and pick one as the answer.

Comment: I wish i could up-vote :) I just started using stackoverflow actively and I don't have 15 reputation required for up vote :D

Comment: @sach: Fair enough. I had forgotten about that restriction.

Comment: Hey i was working on that fix again and found that script is only removing single space not multiple spaces. Eg. {3P Test } * 1 + 0.45% (Which is with single space is working fine), but if column value is {3P Test } * 1 + 0.45% , script is not working it just removing all the spaces. Any suggestion for this ? I tired your script also (As u suggested it is taking long time)

Comment: Sorry could not indent column value properly. I want to remove spaces when column value is something like  {3P Test  spaces spaces spaces spaces spaces} * 1 + 0.45%

Comment: @sach: 1) you can do inline code by enclosing it in `single   back-quotes "\`"`, 2) I am confused as to what did not work as you said _script is not working_ but did not say which script, 3) have you tried the SQL# RegEx function?

Comment: Thanks ! Your first script is not working when there are multiple spaces in-between character and '}' bracket .eg `{3P Test              } * 1 + 0.45%`

Comment: and how can i use RegEx function to remove the spaces?

Comment: @sach: 1) I am not sure how the top script does not work with multiple spaces as it is a working example of doing just that, 2) I can update that script later to be a little faster, 3) please see my second script which is an example of using Regular Expressions (start reading at "But if...")

Comment: @sach, I just posted an update (middle code block) if you really want to stick with T-SQL.

Comment: @sach: no problem. Did it work?  If so, can you please mark the answer as such, or if another answer here worked then mark it as chosen? You can do that even if you can't upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Yes your answer worked ..Thanks for quick reply..also I also wrote a query which runs in loop and removes unwanted space.

Answer (score 1):

how about something along the lines of, [**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a8f6/5)

```
SELECT
    l + '{' + rtrim(m) + '}' + r
  FROM
(
SELECT
    substring([Column], 0, a) l,
    substring([Column], a + 1, b - a - 1) m,
    substring([Column], b + 1, len([Column])- b) r
  FROM
(
SELECT
    [Column],
    charindex('{', [Column]) a,
    charindex('}', [Column]) b
  FROM
    [Table]
) [Pos]) [Bits]
```

---

As you'll note the previous statement just *Selects* the corrected data. You can update it like this,
[**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a8f6/6)

```
UPDATE [Table]
    SET [Column] = l + '{' + rtrim(m) + '}' + r
  FROM
(
SELECT
    [Column],
    substring([Column], 0, a) l,
    substring([Column], a + 1, b - a - 1) m,
    substring([Column], b + 1, len([Column])- b) r
  FROM
(
SELECT
    [Column],
    charindex('{', [Column]) a,
    charindex('}', [Column]) b
  FROM
    [Table]
) [Pos]) [Bits]
JOIN [Table] ON [Table].[Column] = [Bits].[Column];
```

This statement could be improved if the primary key of `[Table]` was known.

Comment: Since you are removing *trailing* spaces only, it is enough to split the string just at `}`.

Comment: @AndriyM, yes, that would be more expedient for this case.

Comment: @Jodrell : Thanks for your solution. Can you tell me what is r in above query. I'm new to sql and trying to understand your query.

Comment: @Jodrell : I used your update script it's working fine if I update specific column. When I'm trying to run query on whole table I'm getting following error,   Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 10
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated.                                 Any thought on this ?

Comment: @sach I suspect that some values do not contain `'{'` or `'}'` or are empty or null strings.

Comment: @Jodrell Ok.Definitely, I will look for such values and then re run the script.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM('{3P Test } * 1 + 0.45%'))

update table set COL1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(COL1))
```

Comment: This will only remove spaces before and after the entire string, not the spaces within the string that the OP is trying to get rid of.

Comment: I think this will remove trailing and leading spaces on the string as a whole, not just within the brackets. e.g. `'  {3P Test } * 1 + 0.45%  '` becomes `{3P Test } * 1+ 0.45%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REPLACE function within a WHILE loop, such as with the following:

```
SELECT '{3P Test   } * 1 + 0.45%' AS TestCol INTO #temp 
UNION 
SELECT '{3P Test } * 1 + 0.45%' 

SELECT * FROM #temp

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE TestCol LIKE '% }%') > 0
  BEGIN
    UPDATE #temp
    SET TestCol = REPLACE(TestCol, ' }', '}')
  END

SELECT * FROM #temp 

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Using `EXISTS` instead of `COUNT(*)` is much more efficient.